# Vertical Scrollbar to bottom always

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I have some code.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messagies}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>     </ScrollViewer>
```

When i added new item, my scrollbar had some offset. How can i set it to bottom always?
I want to see new item, when i added it into the listBox.

Comment: Try to look at this: http://alperguc.blogspot.it/2008/11/c-textbox-auto-scroll-to-end.html

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a valid question.

Comment: Here is the answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/2242592/352101

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/2242592/352101. Its a nice decision. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var lbi  = // the ListBoxItem you're interested in, i.e. the one you added.
MyListBox.ScrollIntoView(lbi);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works! But, can i set some property in xaml for ListBox or ScrollViewer to take this behaviour?

Comment: You know, on this site it's customary to select the answer as correct if it helped you. This should solve the problem of doing it with XAML: http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/listbox-automatically-scroll-currentitem-into-view/