# Animate newly added item in Listbox

Tags: wpf

I am trying to add animation to newly added item and/or changed item in my listbox, this is what i've done so far:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle4" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This animates every item in my listbox.

Comment: @Tejus Is it possible to send command from code to run animation on a single item. Something like: `listBox12.Items.GetItemAt(i)`

Comment: I am not 100% sure. But try changing your RoutedEvent to SourceUpdated.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Hey Check this out. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242571/event-handler-that-will-be-called-when-an-item-is-added-in-a-listbox

Comment: Found another article similar to what you are doing. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269505/sliding-effect-when-adding-new-items-to-a-wpf-listbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event handler that will be called when an item is added in a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242571/event-handler-that-will-be-called-when-an-item-is-added-in-a-listbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a working example explained in this article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Toast

It applies the animation via itemcontainerstyle:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="LightGray">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.2" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:1.2" FillBehavior="Stop">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <BounceEase Bounces="2" Bounciness="6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

Also addressed is animating before removal.